# Jquery closest tr from this fails, why?

Tags: jquery, this, closest, this-pointer

Jquery is not my strong suit. This seems logically correct though it is not working. I have searched everything from find, to closest, to this, etc. I cannot figure out why this is not working.

WHat I am trying to do is add a class to the closest `tr` when `this` `<span>` is clicked.

I get no errors, but I also get no results.

CODE:

```
$curTable .= "
    <tr bgcolor='#f2e2f2' onmouseover=style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'; onmouseout=style.backgroundColor='#f2e2f2';>
        <td>$typeSelect</td>
        <td>$cfilename</td>
        <td><input type='text' size='20' name='cexpDate' class='dp exp' value='$cexpDate' /><script type='text/javascript'>$('.dp').datetimepicker({format:'m/d/Y'});</script></td>
        <td>$catSelect</td>
        <td>$cdateAdded</td>
        <td>$caddedBy</td>
        <td><span class='mod' onclick=\"deleteFile('{$cid}','{$cfilename2}');\">delete</span> | <span class='mod' onclick='modFile($cid)'>modify</span></td>
    </tr>";
```

Jquery:

```
function deleteFile(fileId,fileName){
    var fileId = fileId;
    var fileName = fileName;
    var test = this;
    //alert(test);
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#rmDeleteOverlay').fadeIn();
    $('#deleteFile').append("<br><br><center>"+fileName+"</center>");
}
```

CSS:

```
.highlight{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

```js
function deleteFile(fileId,fileName){
 var fileId = fileId;
 var fileName = fileName;
 var test = this;
 //alert(test);
 $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
 $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
 $('#rmDeleteOverlay').fadeIn();
 $('#deleteFile').append("<br><br><center>"+fileName+"</center>");
}
```

```css
.highlight{
 background-color:#000;
 
}
.mod{
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#a45127;
}
.mod:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr bgcolor='#f2e2f2' onmouseover=style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF'; onmouseout=style.backgroundColor='#f2e2f2';>
   <td><select name='type'><option value='spec'>SPEC</option><option selected value='clg'>CLG</option><option value='coa'>COA</option><option value='gmo'>GMO</option><option value='allergen'>ALLERGEN</option><option value='audit'>AUDIT</option><option value='cor'>COR</option><option value='organic'>ORGANIC</option><option value='kosher'>KOSHER</option><option value='oth'>OTHER</option></select></td>
   <td><a href='/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf' target='_blank'>46_clg_20190620223443.pdf</a></td>
   
   <td><select name='cat'><option selected value='cur'>Current</option><option value='oth'>Other</option><option value='arc'>Archive</option></select></td>
   <td>2019-06-20 22:34:43</td>
   <td><a href='editUser.php?id=11'>11</a></td>
   <td><span class='mod' onclick="deleteFile('1','<a href=\'/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf\' target=\'_blank\'>46_clg_20190620223443.pdf</a>');">delete</span> | <span class='mod' onclick='modFile(1)'>modify</span></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the *rendered* HTML, ideally in a runnable Stack Snippet (not in PHP, which we can't run, since we don't have access to your full source code), so we can see the error for ourselves?

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers. Bind properly with `.on()`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Added snippet.

Comment: When you call a function from `onclick`, it doesn't set `this`. You need to pass the element explicitly.

Comment: @j08691 It may be off topic, but can you explain why? I have done some research on inline vs bind and all I could find was "it is frowned upon". Seems to me it is 6 in one half dozen another. Again, I am not strong with jquery.

Comment: (OffT) The `<center>` tag is obsolete - you should use CSS instead. Same goes for your inline JS `onmouse*` Again, use `:hover` instead. It's commn sometimes to overthink a task and overcomplicate it. And don't use HTML-inline `onclick` as well. Use `.addEventListener('click', someFn)` instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I use CSS 90% of the time falling back to simple HTML when script generated without need for major styling. Rudimentary, but still functional.

Comment: @Sabyre stop doing it now. Thank me later. ;) :D

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Shouldn't the same go for my `<table>`'s? =) Shouldn't I be using `display:grid;` or `display:flex`? Again, I usually do except when pulling data from a DB. Old habits man....

Comment: @Sabyre no. Semantics. Here's a nice read... https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/examples/tables/table-of-divs-experiment/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the information! Especially @Barmar & @sscotti

So as it turns out the issue was 3 fold.

1. Passing the element info to the function and the use of `this`. When calling the function behind the click event `onClick="deleteFile()"` I was trying to get the function to reference the clicked element and ignorantly assumed that element info was automatically passed. @Barmar pointed out that I needed to include `this` as a parameter in the function call.
2. The syntax I was using originally in the `<tr>` for the `onMouse*` events was incorrect. I was using `onMouseOver=style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';` This was breaking the `<tr>` tag. I should have noticed this in jsFiddle, but I didn't. Thank you @sscotti for pointing that out. The line should have been `onMouseOver="style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';"` and similar for `onMouseOut`.
3. Further research based on @Barmar mentioning inline style overwriting the CSS lead me to CSS Specificity. Specificity is a basic browser rule with a point system. Where the victor will be the one with the most points. Inline style = 1000, id = 100, class = 10, element = 1.

Using the `onMouse*` events to change style was equal to 1000 points. I was tring to change that same style in my function by issuing an `addClass()` which is worth 10 points. The inline style declarations trumped that call, thus the class was ignored.

By removing the inline `onMouse*` style declarations from the `<tr>` and moving those to a css class it demoted them from worth 1000 points to being worth 10. Since they are now the same value as the `addClass()` another basic browser rule is used. When points match, last wins.

Thanks everyone who contributed and helped lead me to the answer. Yes I know some of my scripting is archaic and rudimentary. Perfection is a human bogeyman, IMO it doesn't exist. I live by function before form, but I love improving my practices.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function like `onclick="deleteFile('{$cid}','{$cfilename2}');`, it doesn't set `this` to the element in the function. You need to pass the element explicitly, as `onclick="deleteFile(this,'{$cid}','{$cfilename2}');`.

You also weren't seeing the style change from the `highlight` class because the `style="background-color: #f2e2f2"` took precedence. I moved that into the CSS and made the style for `.highlight` more specific. Also, use `:hover` in the CSS instead of `onmouseover`.

```js
function deleteFile(element, fileId, fileName) {
  $(element).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#rmDeleteOverlay').fadeIn();
  $('#deleteFile').append("<br><br><center>" + fileName + "</center>");
}
```

```css
tr {
  background-color: #f2e2f2;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

tr.highlight {
  background-color: #000;
}

.mod {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #a45127;
}

.mod:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select name='type'>
        <option value='spec'>SPEC</option>
        <option selected value='clg'>CLG</option>
        <option value='coa'>COA</option>
        <option value='gmo'>GMO</option>
        <option value='allergen'>ALLERGEN</option>
        <option value='audit'>AUDIT</option>
        <option value='cor'>COR</option>
        <option value='organic'>ORGANIC</option>
        <option value='kosher'>KOSHER</option>
        <option value='oth'>OTHER</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><a href='/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf' target='_blank'>46_clg_20190620223443.pdf</a></td>

    <td>
      <select name='cat'>
        <option selected value='cur'>Current</option>
        <option value='oth'>Other</option>
        <option value='arc'>Archive</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>2019-06-20 22:34:43</td>
    <td><a href='editUser.php?id=11'>11</a></td>
    <td><span class='mod' onclick="deleteFile(this, '1','<a href=\'/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf\' target=\'_blank\'>46_clg_20190620223443.pdf</a>');">delete</span> | <span class='mod' onclick='modFile(1)'>modify</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There's also no need for things like

```
var fileId = fileId;
```

Function parameters are already local variables, you don't need to re-declare them.

Comment: Your answer makes a ton a sense however it still is not working. Again, no errors, no results.

Comment: I have to leave for an hour, I'll implement it in your snippet when I return

Comment: @Sabyre I've updated my answer. You need to change how you're setting the background color styles, because the inline style was overriding the CSS.

Comment: After I removed the `onMouseOver` & `onMouseOut` from the `<tr>` and added `this` to the call and `element` to the function it works flawlessly. See the comment on @sscotti's answer. I now understand that the element needs to be passed to the function to use. I also understand that the duplicate declaration was ridiculous. I still have the `bgcolor=''` in the `<tr>` It seems like the `onMouse*=style.backgroundColor=''` was breaking the `<tr>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

To demonstrate what @Barmar already stated, here's code proof:

```js
function foo(context) {
  context.closest('div').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus omnis et dolorem nobis?
  <button onclick="foo()">click me</button> Harum, aspernatur molestias at asperiores veniam sit pariatur aut animi, dignissimos consequatur quam quo earum dolor quod?</div>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus omnis et dolorem nobis?
  <button onclick="foo(this)">click me, this time passing context</button> Harum, aspernatur molestias at asperiores veniam sit pariatur aut animi, dignissimos consequatur quam quo earum dolor quod?</div>
```

If you want to use `this`, you need to use `addEventListener` (which you should do anyway, inline event listeners are **really bad**:

```js
function foo() {
  this.closest('div').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}

baz.addEventListener('click', foo);
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus omnis et dolorem nobis?
  <button id="baz">click me</button> Harum, aspernatur molestias at asperiores veniam sit pariatur aut animi, dignissimos consequatur quam quo earum dolor quod?</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I do understand that point and have adjusted code to fit @Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the issue, but in JSFiddle(and elsewhere you might have to have the tr enclosed by table tags.  That seemed to be a problem for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
<tr id = "rowelement">
  <td><select name='type'>
  <option value='spec'>SPEC</option>
  <option selected value='clg'>CLG</option>
  <option value='coa'>COA</option>
  <option value='gmo'>GMO</option>
  <option value='allergen'>ALLERGEN</option>
  <option value='audit'>AUDIT</option>
  <option value='cor'>COR</option>
  <option value='organic'>ORGANIC</option>
  <option value='kosher'>KOSHER</option>
  <option value='oth'>OTHER</option>
  </select>
  </td>
    <td><a href='/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf' target='_blank'>46_clg_20190620223443.pdf</a></td>

<td>
<select name='cat'>
<option selected value='cur'>Current</option>
<option value='oth'>Other</option>
<option value='arc'>Archive</option>
</select>
</td>

<td>2019-06-20 22:34:43</td>
<td><a href='editUser.php?id=11'>11</a></td>
<td><span id ="delete" class='mod' data-file = "1" data-filepath = "/uploads/rm/46/46_clg_20190620223443.pdf">delete</span> | <span id ="mod" class='mod' onclick='modFile($cid)'>modify</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Not sure if the JS works for you, but if you can put the params for the function in data attributes, that would be one method.

```
$("#rowelement").on("mouseover", function(e) {
    $(this).css("background", "#FFFFFF");
});
$("#rowelement").on("mouseout", function(e) {
    $(this).css("background", "#f2e2f2");
});

$("#delete").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var fileId = $(this).data("file");
    var fileName = $(this).data("filepath");
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");
    // ??? $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    // ??? $('#rmDeleteOverlay').fadeIn();
    // ???$('#deleteFile').append("<br><br><center>"+fileName+"</center>");
});
```

CSS

```
.highlight{
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.mod{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #a45127;
}
.mod:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#rowelement {
  background: #f2e2f2;
}
```

Comment: Removing the `onMouse*` events from the `<tr>` and incorporating the information that @Barmar provided worked. Though I am not sure why.